# How can I learn what border crossing a bus between Malaysia and Indonesia will use?

Tags: borders, buses, malaysia, indonesia, borneo

A few bus companies, including e.g. [Bus Asia](https://busasia.my/busasia/), offer service between Kuching, Malaysia, and Pontianak, Indonesia, both on the island of Borneo (Kalimantan).

Plugging those cities into Google Maps [reveals](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Kuching,+Sarawak,+Malaysia/Pontianak,+West+Kalimantan,+Indonesia/@0.8075426,109.7097873,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x31fb0784258cbf11:0xd37257591ab17e72!2m2!1d110.359503!2d1.5533785!1m5!1m1!1s0x2e1d58f604b0799b:0x511ef9501fc9ffe3!2m2!1d109.3425039!2d-0.0263303!3e0?entry=ttu) a few different routes that might do the job, crossing the Malaysian/Indonesian border at Entikong, Jagoi Babang, or Aruk; it is possible that other routes may be possible as well.

However, visitors to Indonesia from many countries may [apply for a Visa on Arrival](https://www.imigrasi.go.id/en/visa-kunjungan-saat-kedatangan/) or pick-up a pre-reserved [Electronic Visa on Arrival](https://www.imigrasi.go.id/en/e-voa/) only at certain border posts. Entikong and Aruk are on the lists, but Jagoi Babang is not and so should be avoided by visitors from those countries who do not wish to obtain a regular tourist visa in advance (which costs IDR 1,500,000 instead of IDR 500,000 and is also more annoying to obtain).

If I am considering undergoing a trip such as this one or elsewhere on Borneo, how can I learn what border crossing the bus is likely to use and thus if I will be able to use the VOA or e-VOA service?

Comment: Via Entikong is the shortest route and I've never heard of a bus using a different crossing.  But I'm not a local and haven't been to Kuching in years, so YMMV.

Comment: You could just ask the bus company. If they have a phone number on their website, chances are high you can use WhatsApp to write them a message. In Malaysia, your may also get an English speaking person on the phone if you just call.

Answer (score 13):

I'm still not sure I have a *general* answer to the question, but I took the bus today and can confirm that the bus did indeed use the crossing at Tebedu/Entikong. My e-VOA was accepted, and the immigration officer told me unprompted that it's fine to buy a VOA at the crossing if you prefer. There are moneychangers in the area between the border posts if you want to take this option but do not arrive with any rupiah. Apparently all, or substantially all, buses on the Kuching/Pontianak route do use this crossing.

Axel's very reasonable suggestion to simply ask the bus company what crossing is used did not work out for me: I was unable to reach them by phone or WhatsApp in advance of my travel. But it remains good advice for travelers on different routes to try, and/or to check guidebooks and simply hope that the most efficient route will be taken.

| exit | entry |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Malaysia exit stamp Tebedu] | [image: Indonesia stay permit ETKG] |